# Arco sulla tastiera

Tags: violin

Does anybody know what the expression `arco sulla tastiera` above a group of 3 notes on a score for violin voice mean and how you will play them on the violin ?
Concerning the notes, all of them have on the top of the stem 2 oblique lines and the first note is connected with the second one with both an arc and a strait line. So does the second note with the third one.

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

*arco sulla tastiera* would be *with the bow on the fingerboard*, or something close, translated literally. So, you'd play it just as you would normally, just on the fingerboard rather than near the bridge. Resulting in a lighter, more airy sound.

Regarding the other markings of the notes, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, is there a possibility you could upload a picture? The arc and straight line could mean it is to be played legato and, depending on where the line is situated, a glissando, but with your explanation I'm not entirely sure. The two oblique lines on the stem could be an abbreviation for you to play semiquavers for the duration of the note but that wouldn't fit particularly well with a glissando, and again, I'd need to see the exact markings to be certain.